# jquery auto complete load when type somthing in search box

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

I use jquery auto complete on my site I have many keywords in auto complete script so my site load slow please tell me any method to load jquery auto complete when user type something on search box this will help to load page fast.
check my site: [www.playorplays.com](http://www.playorplays.com)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var availableTags = ["", ""];
var otherTags = [
        "Video",
        "Song",
        "Full",
        "Movie",
        "HD",
        "1080p",
        ""];
var faux = $("#faux");
var offsets;
var arrayused;
var calcfaux;
var retresult;
var checkspace;
var contents = $('#s')[0];
var carpos;
var fauxpos;
var tier;
var startss;
var endss;

function getCaret(el) {
    if (el.selectionStart) {
        return el.selectionStart;
    } else if (document.selection) {
        el.focus();
        var r = document.selection.createRange();
        if (r == null) {
            return 0;
        }
        var re = el.createTextRange(),
            rc = re.duplicate();
        re.moveToBookmark(r.getBookmark());
        rc.setEndPoint('EndToStart', re);
        return rc.text.length;
    }
    return 0;
}

function split(val) {
    return val.split(/ \s*/);
}

function extractLast(term) {
    return split(term).pop();
}
$("#s").on("keydown", function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB && $(this).data("autocomplete").menu.active) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
}).click(function(event) {
    carpos = getCaret(contents);
    fauxpos = faux.text().length;
    if (carpos < fauxpos) {
        tier = "close";
        $(this).autocomplete("close");
        startss = this.selectionStart;
        endss = this.selectionEnd;
        $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/ *$/, ''));
        this.setSelectionRange(startss, endss);
    } else {
        tier = "open";
    }
}).on("keyup", function(event) {
    calcfaux = faux.text($(this).val());
    fauxpos = faux.text().length;
    if (/ $/.test(faux.text()) || tier === "close") {
        checkspace = "space";
    } else {
        checkspace = "nospace";
    } if (fauxpos <= 1) {
        offsets = 0;
        tier = "open";
    }
    carpos = getCaret(contents);
    if (carpos < fauxpos) {
        tier = "close";
        $(this).autocomplete("close");
        startss = this.selectionStart;
        endss = this.selectionEnd;
        $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/ *$/, ''));
        this.setSelectionRange(startss, endss);
    } else {
        tier = "open";
    }
}).autocomplete({
    minLength: 1,
    search: function(event, ui) {
        var input = $(event.target);
        if (checkspace === "space") {
            input.autocomplete("close");
            return false;
        }
    },
    source: function(request, response) {
        var terme = $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(extractLast(request.term)),
            startsWithMatchere = new RegExp("^" + terme, "i"),
            startsWithe = $.grep(availableTags, function(value) {
                return startsWithMatchere.test(value.label || value.value || value);
            }),
            containsMatchere = new RegExp(terme, "i"),
            containse = $.grep(availableTags, function(value) {
                return $.inArray(value, startsWithe) < 0 && containsMatchere.test(value.label || value.value || value);
            });
        var term = $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(extractLast(request.term)),
            startsWithMatcher = new RegExp("^" + term, "i"),
            startsWith = $.grep(otherTags, function(value) {
                return startsWithMatcher.test(value.label || value.value || value);
            }),
            containsMatcher = new RegExp(term, "i"),
            contains = $.grep(otherTags, function(value) {
                return $.inArray(value, startsWith) < 0 && containsMatcher.test(value.label || value.value || value);
            });
        if (offsets == 0) {
            retresult = startsWithe.concat(containse);
            arrayused = "availableTags";
            response(startsWithe.concat(containse));
        }
        if (retresult == "" || offsets != 0) {
            arrayused = "otherTags";
            response(startsWith.concat(contains));
        }
    },
    open: function(event, ui) {
        var input = $(event.target),
            widget = input.autocomplete("widget"),
            style = $.extend(input.css(["font", "border-left", "padding-left"]), {
                position: "absolute",
                visibility: "hidden",
                "padding-right": 0,
                "border-right": 0,
                "white-space": "pre",
                "font-size": "16px",
                "font-weight": "bold"
            }),
            div = $("<div/>"),
            pos = {
                my: "left top",
                collision: "none"
            },
            offset = 0;
        div.text(input.val().replace(/\S*$/, "")).css(style).insertAfter(input);
        offset = Math.min(Math.max(offset + div.width(), 0), input.width() - widget.width());
        if (arrayused === "otherTags") {
            widget.css("width", "");
            offset = Math.min(Math.max(offset + div.width(), 0), input.width() - widget.width());
        }
        div.remove();
        pos.at = "left+" + offset + " bottom";
        input.autocomplete("option", "position", pos);
        widget.position($.extend({
            of: input
        }, pos));
        offsets = offset;
    },
    focus: function() {
        return false;
    },
    select: function(event, ui) {
        var terms = split(this.value);
        terms.pop();
        terms.push(ui.item.value);
        terms.push("");
        this.value = terms.join(" ");
        calcfaux = faux.text($(this).val());
        if (/ $/.test(faux.text())) {
            checkspace = "space";
        } else {
            checkspace = "nospace";
        }
        carpos = getCaret(contents);
        fauxpos = faux.text().length;
        return false;
    }
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to avoid triggering auto completing for the single key entry;Wait at least user enter three key board inputs.

And if your keep your key words in a static array it wont be affect to the speed of the page load.

But the size of your images, .css files, .js files will directly affect to speed of the page load.

try to compress those files and use light weight images.

And try to reduce the round trip time. In order to do that use your basic styling in your html page.

and do research in how to reduce the page load time.

and check your site  with google developer page speed insights (https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/)

and read the tips.....

Comment: how to keep key words in a static array?

Comment: your already doing it...var otherTags = [
        "Video",
        "Song",
        "Full",
        "Movie",
        "HD",
        "1080p",
        ""];

Comment: ok if i add thousands of words in this script it could not effect on page load speed?